# trying to find a more efficient algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

A binary string is a string where each character is either '0' or '1'. A binary string S is good if and only if for every substring of S, the number of '0's is less than or equal to the number of '1's.

A substring of string S can be obtained by deleting several (or zero) characters from the beginning of S and several (or zero) characters from the end of S, leaving at least two characters from S. For example, if S = "abcdfab", then "abcd", "fab", "bcdfa", "abcdfab" are substrings of S, while "abab", "", "d", and "adcdab" are not substring of S.

I am trying to figure out a way to check if a binary string of length N is good.

The naive way is to check every substring of this binary string which has the time complexity of O(N^2), is there an algorithm which can have a time complexity of O(N) or better?

Comment: 1) Binary substring is a very well studied problem.  2) Off-topic for SO.  Try https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking algorithm questions here; that's what the algorithm tag is for. But please give your questions a more descriptive title; everyone's "trying to find a more efficient algorithm".

Answer (score 5):

In order for every single (two-or-more-character) substring to have at least as many ones as zeros, there can be no consecutive zeros - in fact, you need at least *two* ones between every pair of zeros. That's because the string `010` is not valid but there's *no* two-character substring of `0110` that violates your constraint.

So the algorithm would be:

```
set oneCount to 2 # Zero at start of string is okay.
for each character ch in string:
    if ch is 0:
        if oneCount is less than 2:
            generate error
        set oneCount to 0
    else:
        increment oneCount
```

That's actually O(n) time but you can actually do better than that by amortising the cost. Since there may be multiple modifying operations on the string before checking, you can defer the checking to bring the amortised cost down.

By that, I mean cache the validity of the string so that, if you check without having modified it, just return the cached value instead of re-checking. That's the coarsest level of amortisation but may result in improvements just on its own:

```
define string = "", dirty = false, cachedValidity = true

define isValid():
    if dirty:
        cachedValidity = true
        set oneCount to 2
        for each character ch in string:
            if ch is 0:
                if oneCount is less than 2:
                    cachedValidity = false
                    exit for loop
                set oneCount to 0
            else:
                increment oneCount
    dirty = false
    return cachedValidity
```

Then you just have to ensure that any operation on the string sets `dirty` to true, something that's actually quite easy in an object-oriented language.

For even more optimisation, you don't need to set `dirty` to true for *all* operations, it actually depends on what you're doing. The string validity will not change under (at least) the following conditions:

1. If you insert a one next to another one.
2. If you delete a one that was between two other ones.
3. If you insert a zero right in the middle if four consecutive ones.

None of these operations affect the validity so they should not set the `dirty` flag. There may be others you can discover under analysis but that's a good start and will allow you to further amortise the cost of checking.

Comment: That cache optimization is valid only if OP is modifying the binary string, or aware of the modifications, right?

Comment: @nipunasudha: yes. If the string can be wrapped into an object where you control the modifications, this optimisation can have a great impact. Otherwise, you're stuck with the O(n) solution. Even *in* that case, it's still better than the O(n^2) posited in the question.

Comment: learning new things! thank you, and an honor to be mentioned by rank 14! :D

Answer (score 2):

Each pair of 0s should have at least two 1s between them. It is O(n).

```
def isGood(bstr):
    count = 2
    for i in bstr:
        if i == '0':
            if count >= 2:
                count = 0
            else:
                return False
        else:
            count += 1
    return True

print(isGood("0010101"))
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes. I edited and added a code. May be not the most elegant python implementation, but you get the idea right?